# can't extend AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, unit-testing

I'm trying to extend the spring unit test abstract class AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests, but eclipse complains of an inconsistent type hierarchy. I've reduced the problem down to a real simple example:

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;

public class HooHa extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

}
```

I have spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar on the classpath for the project, so eclipse is finding the class, it just doesn't like it.

The error message that eclipse gives is:

```
The hierarchy of the type HooHa is inconsistent
```

Any help or insight anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One of the core Spring library is missing .You need to include it in your project java build path. Please provide all the jar details.

Comment: Yup! In addition to spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar, ya need spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar and spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar on the classpath. Thank you for the hint. :-)